# Populate activeX ListBox from range on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, range

I have an axctiveX listbox that will populate from a range on the same sheet but when I try and populate it from another sheet it just comes up blank. No error message, it's just empty.

What's interesting is that while the values don't populate there are the correct number of items (16). If I set the range to "A1:A2" then the LB has only two blank items.

The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim r As Range, data As Range

    Set r = Me.Range("c2")

    Dim objOLE As OLEObject, objListBox As MSForms.ListBox

    Set objOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=r.Left, Top:=r.Top, Width:=r.Width, Height:=100)

    With objOLE
        .Name = "blah"

        ' *********this does work*************
        objOLE.ListFillRange = Me.Range("D1:D16").Address

         '********this does not work************
'        objOLE.ListFillRange = Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:A16").Address

        Set objListBox = .Object
        ' toggle visibility to ensure the control is clickable
        .Visible = False
        .Visible = True
    End With

    With objListBox
        .multiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) property does not include the worksheet name unless you specify the `extenal:=True` optional parameter. However, in that case, you get both the workbook as an external reference and the worksheet name. Probably best to construct a string with the worksheet name as well as the cell address.

```
With objOLE
    .Name = "blah"
    '.ListFillRange = "'Sheet6'!A1:A16"
    .ListFillRange = "'" & Sheets("Sheet6").Name & "'!" & Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:A16").Address
End With
```

Comment: thanks so much. Worked first try.  Never would have figured that out.